# SQLAlchemy circular one-to-one relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am trying to make a circular one-to-one relationship (not sure what the correct term is) with SQLAlchemy that looks the following:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child_id = db.Column(db.Integer,db.ForeignKey("children.id", use_alter=True))
    child = db.relationship("Child",
                        uselist=False,
                        foreign_keys=[child_id],
                        post_update=True)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("parents.id"))
    user = db.relationship("Parent",
                       uselist=False,
                       foreign_keys=[parent_id])
```

Everything works as expected until I try to `db.drop_all()` and I get an error that the `sqlalchemy.sql.schema.ForeignKeyConstraint` `name` is `None`. Am I doing something wrong when trying to make this circular one-to-one relationship? I would really like to be able to query just the single column to get the id of the other one, hence the circular reference.

Comment: Plural table names should be made illegal :D

Comment: have you tried `child = db.relationship("Child", cascade="all,delete")`?

Comment: Add a full traceback to your post.

Comment: In you parent class, shouldn't `id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)` be `id = db.Column(Integer, primary_key=True)` ? I am guessing you are importing sqlalchemy as db ... in which case I am not sure why you are not getting an error, but perhaps your parent class id could end up being None.

Comment: Please include what DB are you using and the full traceback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [SQLAlchemy Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html):

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    child = relationship("Child", uselist=False, back_populates="parent")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
    parent = relationship("Parent", back_populates="child")
```

Then you can Parent.child or Child.parent all day long